# CSS hyperlink placing

Tags: css, firefox

This is a problem with the hyperlinks on a webpage.It is a CSS issue where the unnecessary style was being applied to all the links in that page and so a wiggling effect is observed when the link is clicked.
It opens fine in google chrome but the problem is with firefox and IE. All the hyperlinks seem to wiggle when clicked (which doesn't happen with chrome) some move up and down when clicked and some move quite a bit.I understand it is a css issue but I dont know what I need to correct.I tried using firebug in firefox but wasn't ale to quite figure out.
Thanks.

Comment: When you've fixed the problem at that live site this question will cease to have value to future readers - can you put together a minimal, complete, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem and can live as part of the question itself?

Comment: I have had this problem only with this site.Do you want me to put the wrong and corrected php part? because that was what was causing the problems.

Comment: If you could put the "wrong" part in the question somewhere that would help make it more useful in the future when someone else reads it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `/themes/mix_and_match/css/custom.css` file, there's a declaration for `#main-wrapper li a.active, #main-wrapper .first a:active` that sets the `display` to `block` and puts a width on active links.  It looks like you are using the `first` class in 2 places so it's being applied in an unintended fashion.  The `<div id="block-system-main` block has a class of first which will make any active links below it pick up this style.

Comment: Thank you.I edited the variable with an if condition so that if does not apply when not required.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there is a `margin-top:-7px` on `:active` status of `a` elements.
Just change it to `margin-top:-9px`. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you.This resolved the issue in the menu bar but the rest of the links are as it is.I kind of understand what I need to do now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is being caused by some CSS being inherited to all your links.  Using FireBug when I comment out the 'display:block' on custom.css this jumping goes away.  However, it also effects other styles.  You may have to refine that style so it doesn't effect other links.

## main-wrapper li a.active, #main-wrapper .first a:active {

```
background: url("../images/navbkgHover.png") repeat-x scroll left top transparent;
display: block;
height: 15px;
margin-top: -7px;
width: 103px;
```

}